# Регулярное выражение для тэга IMG

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите написать регулярку для тэга `img`, если:

```
<img src="http://someurl/a79a2277b00a43efc4f5d3fce8b0fba6.gif" id="MyID">
```

Мне, собственно, нужно значение атрибута `src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если Кому понадобиться:**

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]*?src=["\']?([^"\'\s>]+)["\']? id="MyID"[^>]*?>/is', $content, $img);
```

Answer (score 1):

`/src="([^"]*)"/`

Comment: текст большой, мне нужны картинки именно с id="MyID"

Answer (score 0):

В shell это выглядит так:

```
echo '<img src="http://someurl/a79a2277b00a43efc4f5d3fce8b0fba6.gif" id="MyID">' | sed -e 's/^.*src=\"\(.*\)\".*id=\"MyID\".*$/\1/g' -
```

может пригодиться...